# The condition 'is empty' is not working in select query of JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql, is-empty, isnull

Lets say a person class has friends in it.

Then

```
select p.friends is empty from person p;
```

throws up IllegalStateException: Unexpected AST org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode

But

```
select p.friends is null from person p;
```

is returning true/false

Is this expected?Is there a work around to get the boolean without extracting the payload and checking if it is empty or not

Comment: How is the second query you posted not the workaround you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is expected. "p.friends is null" is a condition that returns true/false only if it is null, while is empty works on collections - you apparently have a basic mapping? How did you map 'friends' in the entity and table? You would need to check the string value within the field, possibly using a case statement to return true/false if it matches your requirements.

Comment: @JensSchauder if the json array is empty ([]) but not null,the second statement  still returns true